# Can we use t-test for large sample..??

Tags: hypothesis-testing

How can I use t-test, my sample size is 368, my sample is dependent in nature as it is collected from same population over two period of time, population s.d is unknown.

Comment: First, N=368 is not a large sample. Second, what do you mean by saying that "sample is dependent in nature"?

Comment: Sir, as much I know sample size more than 30 is called as large sample.

Comment: "Sample is dependent in nature" I mean I have collected data regarding income of a population before and after the micro financial assistance. my first sample is income before treatment and another is income after the treatment. both are related to each other thats why they are dependent in nature, they are not independent sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [paired t-test (ref Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test#Paired_samples). It forms one sample by examining the before-and-after differences.

To implement this in Excel, use the code `=TTEST()` with the `type` option (last argument) equal to 1 for paired data, i.e. `=TTEST(A1:A368,B1:B368,2,1)`

Comment: Thanks sir, but one more confusion is there that is that fine to use paired t-test for 368 sample size..??

Comment: @ChandanSingh: absolutely fine. With t-test, the larger the sample the better, due to central limit theorem. If the sample size were less than 30, then I would advise caution. But a larger sample size is a blessing in statistics.